# pipe viewer does not copy the file when told to

Tags: linux

I am trying to use Pipe Viewer command like so:

```
pv -cN  cp file.txt /home/user/Desktop/test/
```

For some reason it does not copy the file.  When use cp without Pipe Viewer it works perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: pv doesn't take an entire pipeline as an argument but is instead meant to be inserted as part of the pipeline and can thus be inserted at any point in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't issue commands to pv like that. This is probably what you are looking for:

```
pv -c file.txt > /home/user/Desktop/test/file.txt
```

pv probably isn't the best tool in this case. You should use `rsync` with the `--progress` flag.

```
rsync --progress file.txt /home/user/Desktop/test/
```